# Finding the correct primitive root of unity for DFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, modular-arithmetic, roots-of-unity

I initially asked this question in cryptography but I think it's better suited for this board.

I'm trying to create a simple code just to show that Blahut's theorem works for binary periodic sequences. (it's a theorem that relates the linear complexity of a sequence with the number of nonzero elements of its DFT). My main question is, **which n-th root of unity do I have to use in the DFT?**

The DFT I have defined is

$B_k=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_j e^{i 2 \pi k j / n}$

Which is just the usual DFT (i is the imaginary unit). As I explain below, I'm not getting the expected result so $e^{i 2 \pi k j / n}$ are probably not the correct roots to choose.

For example:

$b^n=0011101$

Is the main period of the periodic sequence that I want to analyze. This sequence has linear complexity 3 by BMA, so by Blahut's theorem I would expect 3 not null elements in the frequency domain (so, 4 null elements). I'm not getting any null elements in $B^n$ so obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @DavidReed yes it needs to be a primitive root of unity, the problem is that I'm not as well versed in general math to know which is the n-th primitive root of unity in the field of binary sequences of length n (as far as I know, that's just the Galois Field of order $2^n$). I chose that form for the root of unity to try something but it's probably wrong.

Comment: @DavidReed as far as I understand, null element should be zero. If you want to check by yourself, all the math is explained in  L Massey, T Schaub - Linear complexity in coding theory

Comment: @DavidReed by the way, k should range from 0 to n-1, just like j. As I said, that's what I understood from the original paper but I might be mistaken...

Comment: A root of unity in the field you are talking about is going to be a binary sequence, is that you're understanding? It wouldn't be a complex exponential.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes I thought about a binary sequence but I don't know how to implement it. I'm reading ways to do it...

Comment: I can't find a construction anywhere. You'll need to find an irreducible polynomial of degree 7 over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to start

Comment: I'll do it for you tomorrow if you cant manage. I'm pretty sick atm. Someone else may know a quicker way here. The only way I know how to do it is find a generator by brute force..

Comment: Blahut's theorem relates the linear complexity and the number of nonzero elements in the DFT for the _finite-field_ DFT whereas you are using the complex-field DFT.  The primitive seventh root of unity is an element of the _finite_ field $\mathbb F_{2^3}$ and not $e^{i2\pi /n}$ the way you have it.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think it should be 7-th primitive root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{2^7}$, I agree that my formulation is wrong but I cant manage to find that root...

Comment: $\mathbb F_{2^7}$ doesn't contain _any_ $7$th roots of unity and so you will never find the root you need. Look in $\mathbb F_{2^3}$ or more generally in $\mathbb F_{2^{3m}}$ for $7$th roots.